# OnClick redirect the user to another url

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I wanted to change bg color in this order: [Black,White,Red,Green,Blue]

```
<body style="background-color:black">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var bg = document.bgColor;
            var e = document.getElementById("tests");

            if (bg == "black")  {e.style.backgroundColor = "white";}
            else if (bg == "white") {e.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
            else if (bg == "red") {e.style.backgroundColor = "green";}
            else if (bg == "green") {e.style.backgroundColor = "blue";}
            else if (bg == "blue") {"<a href="/testson"/>";}
                        }

    </script>
    <div class="test"; onclick="test()"></div>
</body>
```

But when I click somewhere on page, nothing happens.

Comment: `div` does not have `onclick` attribute

Comment: How do you click on an empty `div`?  Why is there a semicolon in your `<div>` element?  What do you expect `document.getElementById("tests")` to return?  What does anything in your question have to do with your title?  What does your browser's debugging console tell you?  (Hint: It's showing you errors.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: @AdamAzad — All HTML elements support the `onclick` attribuet

Comment: put some content in .test div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is that div tags do not support the action `onclick`. In order to make the div clickable, you would need to set an ID for the div and then in javascript assign an event handler to process the click for example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var bg = document.bgColor;
            var e = document.getElementById("tests");

            if (bg == "black")  {
                e.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
            else if (bg == "white") {
                e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            else if (bg == "red") {
                e.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
            else if (bg == "green") {
                e.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }
            else if (bg == "blue") {
                "<a href="/testson"/>";
            }
        }
        function AddHandlers(){
            var something = document.getElementById('someid');

            something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            something.onclick = function() {
                 test();
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="AddHandlers()">
    <div class="test" id="someid">Click me!!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
 // similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

remove `;` from html

```
 <div class="test" onclick="test()">Click me!!</div>
```